# pip installation failure on raspberry pi

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi, pip, obd-ii

i have the new raspberry pi and i am trying to install package "pip install library" However an error occurs  " could not create 'usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/obd' : permission denied"

IF anyone could help that would really be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you are trying to run `pip` as a an unprivileged user when you probably need to run it as `root`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [Virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/):

Create a "virtualenv" directory to store your future virtualenvs... For example, in your home directory.

Install Virtualenv, of course. If you have a recent version of Python, it is already done.

Then process like this for each project:

```
virtualenv my_project
source my_project/bin/activate
pip install a_library
```

It's a best practice: avoid polluting your system-wide Python.